# python blackjack game, seems to be ignoring 'if' statement

Tags: python, if-statement, python-2.7

I've been trying to make a simple blackjack game in python and I seem to be stuck, my code is as follows:

```
from random import choice

def deck():
    cards = range(1, 12)
    return choice(cards)

def diack():
    card1= deck()
    card2 = deck()
    hand = card1 + card2
    print hand
    if hand < 21:
         print raw_input("Would you like to hit or stand?")
         if "hit":
             return hand + deck()
         elif "stand": 
             return hand
```

When I run that it seems to work for "hit" but when I type in "stand" it seems to "hit" aswell. As you can probably tell by now I am extremely new to programming. Could you guys help point me in the right direction on how to make my game work (I'd like to use as much of my code as possible).

Comment: This is just going to give you an indentation error, because the second `if` is indented under `print`, which isn't a control statement. Please post your actual code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`if "hit"` just tests if the string `"hit"` exists, and it does. Thus, the `elif` statement is never executed.

You need to capture the user input in a variable and test against that instead:

```
choice = raw_input("Would you like to hit or stand?")
print choice
if choice == "hit":
    return hand + deck()
elif choice == "stand": 
    return hand
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I see what I was doing wrong, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you get the indentation right:

```
print raw_input("Would you like to hit or stand?")
if "hit":
    return hand + deck()
elif "stand": 
    return hand
```

Your `if` is just checking whether the string `"hit"` is true. All non-empty strings are true, and `"hit"` is non-empty, so this will always succeed.

What you want is something like this:

```
cmd = raw_input("Would you like to hit or stand?")
if cmd == "hit":
    return hand + deck()
elif cmd == "stand": 
    return hand
```

Now you're checking whether the result of `raw_input` is the string `"hit"`, which is what you want.

Comment: Thank you! It seems to be working now. On another note is their a way to copy and paster over code into stackoverflow while maintaing the indentation?

Comment: I just copy out of emacs, paste into the window, and click the `{}` button to indent the selection 4 spaces.