# Invalid syntax on if else statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

I'm writing a simple text-based game and I've run into an error here.

```python
def lamp():
    print "You pick up the lamp and examine it."
    print "It looks like an ordinary gas lamp."
    print "What do you do?"

    lamp_action = raw_input("> ")

    if "rub" in lamp_action:
        rub()
    elif "break" or "smash" in lamp_action:
        print "The lamp shatters into pieces."
        dead("The room disappears and you are lost in the void.")
    else:
        lamp()
```

If I comment out the elif part, Python gives an invalid syntax error on else. If I leave the elif part in, the program will run without an error, but even typing something random like "aaaaaa" will follow the elif action.

I also doesn't work if I replace the else section with something like this:

```python
else: 
    print "That's not a good idea."
    lamp()
```

or like this:

```python
else: 
    dead("That's not a good idea.")
```

Where dead is:

```python
def dead(why):
    print "%s Game over." % why
    exit(0)
```

What did I miss?

Comment: possible duplicate of [python blackjack game, seems to be ignoring 'if' statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646883/python-blackjack-game-seems-to-be-ignoring-if-statement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"break" or "smash" in lamp_action` is interpreted by Python as testing `"break"`, then testing `"smash" in lamp_action`. Since `"break"` is a nonempty string, it is always interpreted as "true", so the `elif` is always taken.

The correct form is

```
elif lamp_action in ('break', 'smash'):
```

i.e. testing if the action is `in` a list of possibilities.

Comment: Thank you, that partially worked. However, is there a way to account for additional user input? For example, running your code now, I entered `"smash"` and it worked as expected. But when I entered `"smash it"`, the program jumped to the `else`.

Is there a way to have the program test to see if the answer contains `"break"` or `"smash"` and then runs the `elif`, despite any other input that goes along with them?

Comment: @pez: in that case, you want `'break' in lamp_action or 'smash' in lamp_action`. Yes, there's repetition, but it isn't easy to avoid there.